# Query InnerJoin Xamarin Android con Sqlite net pcl

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, xamarin.android

Tengo un query en sqlite donde hago varios inner join

```
    var query1 = db.Query<Color>("select ar.Estilo, co.Nombre as Color, ac.Nombre as Acabado, ma.Nombre as Marca,te.Nombre as Otoño, su.Nombre as SubLinea from  Articulo as ar inner join Acabado as ac on ar.IdAcabado = ac.IdAcabado inner join Clasificacion as cl on ar.IdClasificacion = cl.IdClasificacion inner join Color as co on ar.IdColor = co.IdColor inner join Marca as ma on ar.IdMarca = ma.IdMarca inner join Sublinea as su on ar.IdSublinea = su.IdSublinea inner join Temporada as te on ar.IdTemporada = te.IdTemporada").ToList();
```

Pero el método, db.Query<>() me pide como parámetro el tipo de Objeto.
Necesito poder usar un tipo de objeto genérico, porque la consulta me trae campos de diferentes tipos de objetos, y pues como es de tipo 'Color' el que actualmente uso, sólo me trae el resultado de esa tabla.

```
 var query1 = db.Query<Color>
```

Necesito cambiar el Objeto Color a algún tipo de objeto Génerico para que la consulta me traiga todo, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto color debe ser una entidad que contenga como propiedades los otras entidades que estás tratando de mapear de tal forma que la consulta devuelva los objetos color que coincidan con la consulta y en sus propiedades traiga las demás entidades